# Loop for multiple dataframes with a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I tried to run a function through multiple data frames, but I have a problem with it. My main questions are:
1) I tried to run a defined function with zip(df1, df2, df3,...) and the outputs are new DF1, DF2, DF3,...; however, I failed. Is it possible to run a function through multiple dataframes and outputs are also dataframes by "zip"?

2) If zip() is not a choice, how do I do to make my function running in a loop? Currently, I just have three dataframes and they are easy to be done separately. But I would like to know how to handle it when I have 50, 100, or even more dataframes.

Here are my codes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns  
#import scipy.stats as ss

# *********** 3 City Temperature files from NOAA ***********
# City 1
df1 = pd.pandas.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uj5N363dEVJZ9WVy2a_kkbJKJnyyE5qnEqOfzO0UCQE/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv')
# City 2
df2 = pd.pandas.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13CgTdDCDzB_3WIYIRVMeLu6E36xzHSzRR5T_Ku0vThA/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv')
# City 3
df3 = pd.pandas.read_csv('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pNZFIaV_NpQfSed-msIGu9jzzqF6JBvCZrBRiU2ZkQ/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv')


def CleanDATA(data):
    data = data.drop(columns=['Annual']) 
    data = data.drop(data.index[29:-1])
    data = data.drop(data.index[-1])
    monthname=[]
    Temp=[]
    for row in range(0,len(data)):
        for col in range(1,13):
            #monthname.append(str(col)+"-"+str(data['Year'][row]))
            monthname.append(str(data['Year'][row])+str(col))
            Temp.append(data.iloc[row,col])

    df0=pd.DataFrame()
    df0['Month']=monthname
    df0['Temperature']=Temp
    df0['Month']=pd.to_datetime(df0['Month'],format='%Y.0%m') #change the date form
    df0['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df0['Month']).dt.date # remove time, only keep date
    data =df0[df0.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)] # remove non-numerical     

    return data


data1 = CleanDATA(df1)
data2 = CleanDATA(df2)
data3 = CleanDATA(df3)
```

Also, I found an issue with Pandas while reading the following excel file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V9fKpACbLrSi0NfB0FHSgc96PQerKkUF/view?usp=sharing  (This is city 1 temperature data from 1990-2019)

2019 is ongoing, hence, NOAA stations only provide information till this May. The excel data labels all missing data by "M". I noticed that once the column comes with an "M", I cannot use boxplot directly even I already drop 2019 row. Spyder console will say "items [Jun to Dec]" are missing (and the wired thing is I can use the same data to plot XY line plot). To plot the boxplot, I have to manually remove 2019 information (1 row) in excel than read the new file.

Comment: Welcome. You probably will get better results asking your second question about the box plots in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using dictionaries (or lists or other iterable).

```
cities = {'city1': 'https://...', 'city2': 'https://...', 'city3': 'https://...'}
df = {}
data = {}
for city, url in iteritems(cities):
    df[city] = pd.pandas.read_csv(url)
    data[city] = CleanDATA(df[city])
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why I use zip(df1,df2,df3,...dfn) doesn't work?